# how to set visible property for div in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I cannot able to access control in the below way

```
document.getElementById("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_divDocSearch").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

but i can able to access as

```
var div = document.getElementById("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_divDocSearch");
div.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

How to access with above line, is there any toggle property available for this ?

Comment: there is no difference in the two methods, may be you need to make sure that your javascript code executes after the document has loaded for unexpected behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function like below

```
function toggle(obj){
    if(obj.style.visibility == "visible")
        obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    else
        obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

And then call them on the each element using `toggle(object)`;

Answer (score 2):

Try

`div.style = 'display:none';`

to hide the div. and thus

`div.style = 'display:inline';` // or block, or whatever you need.

to display the div.

EDIT:

Just foudn this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

so it looks like you can do

`div.visibility = 'hidden';`

Comment: any toggle property available for display.
I am having 5 div and i need to display the div based on the string. so is there any toggle property available?

Comment: A `div`'s default display property is `block`, not `inline`.

Comment: @user96888 how do you wish to change the visibility? you can write a custom function to do that

Comment: @sunilMishra : i am doing it by assigning all the div to hide and again i am assigining particular div to visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("<%= divDocSearch.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I need with out using variable

Answer (score 0):

You can call the below function on click of all those divs passing in the id of the particular div being clicked. It finds all divs by using document.getElementsByTagName and hides them. Then it again makes visible the div whose id is passed

```
function showdiv(divid) {
  divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  count=divs.length;
  for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
    divs[i].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
  document.getElementById(divid).style.visibility="visible";
}
```